# Upgrade to 16.04 causing huge problems

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb

I have an Inspiron 3551 with Ubuntu. Today there was a notification asking for upgrade to 16.04 and I clicked for upgrade. Upgrade did not finish and the system went on hang. When I restarted the system it asked me to select from one of the 4 options. The first option *Ubuntu took me nowhere and the system went on hang. Upon restart I used option 4 Factory Reset took me to Version 13.10. When I tried to Upgrade it is not happening again system went on hang. In short neither upgrade happened nor is the laptop working now. Is there a remedy?

Answer (score 0):

Likely not. If the installation was interrupted, there could be corrupted files and all sorts of other problems.

Burn an Ubuntu 16.04 [ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso?_ga=1.118792713.1264774025.1470761958) file to a USB flash drive using [Rosa Image Writer](http://wiki.rosalab.com/en/index.php/ROSA_ImageWriter#Where_can_I_take_it.3F).

Boot from the USB drive, mount your old partition (it should appear as a drive you can click on in the file manager) and make backups of all your important files. Then do a fresh install with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thank you for the solution provided. I do not have a cd drive. Is a download available. Could u please provide the link.

Comment: I edited the answer and added links.